# Combing multiple orWhere() in Laravel 9 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-orwhere

Is it possible to combine multiple `orWhere()` inside one `where()`?

E.g. The following:

```
$query->where(function($query){
    $query->where('text1', '=', $_GET['lorem'])
        ->orWhere('text2', '=', $_GET['lorem'])
        ->orWhere('text3', '=', $_GET['lorem'])
        ->orWhere('text4', '=', $_GET['lorem']);
});
```

Would look something like this:

```
$query->where(function($query){
    $query->where(['text1' || 'text2' || 'text3' || 'text4'], '=', $_GET['lorem']);
});
```

**P.S.** In the above hypothetical example, the `[` `]` aren't really referring to an array but I'm just using the brackets to group `text1/2/3/4`.

Comment: concat those columns and then do the LIKE on the concatenated string.

Comment: @nice_dev Oh yeah.... But what if it's `=` instead of `like` though? Check the updated code snippet in the question.

Comment: If you are using `%`, you _should not_ use `=`. `LIKE` is the correct way to treat `%` as a special character and not just a single percent sign.

Comment: @nice_dev I've removed the `%` from the example code snippet. Mistakenly left them there while changing the queries from `like` to `=` earlier.

Comment: Ok, but you initially had `%` and now `=`. For which one you wish to shorten your query?

Comment: @nice_dev For `=`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249420/discussion-between-andrewl64-and-nice-dev).

Comment: Hmm... in your question, you have combined multiple orWhere's what is your problem with that solution? I feel like this question is more of an statement than a question or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: Raw SQL for this should be something like `where $_GET['lorem'] IN (text1, text2, text3, text4)`. **P.S**.- Not tested this yet.

Comment: @mrhn I feel the same. I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: For what purpose ? remove readability ? make maintaining the code more hard ? there is no gain in doing so. Only solution is to extend your builder to add a method that take an array of field names and the value to compare them to and do what you already did inside of it. other than that, it's useless to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->where(function($query){
$columns = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];
foreach($columns as $column){
$query->OrWhere($column, '=', $_GET['lorem']);}});
```

This might work

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$columns = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];
$query->where(function ($query) use ($columns) {
    foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
        if ($key == 0) $query->where($column, '=', $_GET['lorem']);
        else $query->OrWhere($column, '=', $_GET['lorem']);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation for this actually does allow you to pass an array of equal statements in a key-value arrangement.

```
$columns = [
'text1'=>$value,
'text2'=>$value,
'text3'=>$value
];

$query->where($columns);
```

You can see this works from the laravel docs in 9.X
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/29430b413b29fb60073ad26682a572df2ab5f5b2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L703

This shows the builder where clause. Following this, are the lines 708-710 which take the array and make it into the looped where statement that has been a solution for you up until now.

Please note that this method seems to only work with `'='` as far as I can see.

TLDR:

Put key-value array into first param of where method.